# Separated controllers and factory modules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I just started learning `AngularJS` and I am at a point of creating controllers and services ( factory ).

My folder structure is like the following:

```
Scripts
|
|-- Controllers
    |
    |-- invoiceController.js
    |-- customerController.js
|
|-- Services
    |
    |-- invoiceServices.js
    |-- customerServices.js
|
|-- app.js
```

Now I want to separate all the logics based on object ( eg Invoices, Customers, ... ).
So that I have a controller and service for my invoices, and one of both for my customers and so on.

But how do I inject the correct service in my controller?

When I try this:

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('skycountApp', [

        invoiceService

    ]);
})();
```

**invoiceController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('skycountApp')
        .controller('InvoiceController', invoiceController);

    invoiceController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Invoices'];

    function homeController($scope, Invoices) {
        $scope.text = Invoices;
    }
})();
```

**invoiceService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var invoiceService = angular.module('invoiceService', ['ngResource']);
    invoiceService.factory('Invoices', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return 'All invoices';
        }
    ]);
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="skycountApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DOTA 2 Heroes</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="InvoiceController">
        <h1>{{text}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I see the message `All invoices`.

But now I have injected the service in the app when it gets created. I will have more services ( one for customers, one for payments, ... ) so injecting them all in the beginning sounds silly to me.

How can I inject the correct service in the correct controller?

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('skycountApp', [

        //invoiceService this is not needed here

    ]);
})();
```

**invoiceController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Its only needed here, how to inject it??????

    angular
        .module('skycountApp')
        .controller('InvoiceController', invoiceController);

    invoiceController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Invoices'];

    function homeController($scope, Invoices) {
        $scope.text = Invoices;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all why you are creating services on the the different angularjs module

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var invoiceService = angular.module('invoiceService', ['ngResource']);
    invoiceService.factory('Invoices', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return 'All invoices';
        }
    ]);
})();
```

simply create service on same angularjs module

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
   angular.module('skycountApp').factory('Invoices',['$resource',
            function ($resource) {
                return 'All invoices';
            }
        ]);
    })();
```

and then in your controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
angular.module('skycountApp').controller('InvoiceController', function(Invoices){
    $scope.text = Invoices;
})();
```

**Note : include `ngResource` in app.js `angular.module`**

**Update : for using service define in other module you need to inject the module**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
angular.module('skycountApp',['invoiceService']).controller('InvoiceController', function(Invoices){
    $scope.text = Invoices;
})();
```

Comment: But why putting all of this in the same module? Isn't it better to split things up? So that you can inject the needed module in the controller?

Comment: no its no way a better approach.you kept our service in a separate file , that's enough.

Comment: So if only the `invoiceController` is present in the html page it will only work with this and doesn't do anything with the other modules and services?

Comment: no you can use the service or factory define in other modules , see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

`InvoiceController` is a part of `skycountApp` module. It is coupled with it, and putting `invoiceService` into separate module doesn't make much sense. Doing

```
angular.module('skycountApp', ['invoiceService']);
```

means only that `invoiceService` was listed as a dependency for the module, and now the module has access to its components. `Invoices` service isn't injected and doesn't cause any overhead when `InvoiceController` isn't used.

If invoice and customer components will rarely be used by the same user, you can make `invoiceService` and `InvoiceController` a part of invoice module and use it only where it is needed (consider this module a separate app). But in the end you will most likely find that all js files have to be built into single bundle for the sake of performance.